# How to change my Group-box style

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro, groupbox

So this is my `GroupBox`:

```
<GroupBox 
    Header="My header"
    Background="Transparent"
    Foreground="Gainsboro"
    BorderBrush="Gainsboro" />
```

[image]

And i have several things that i want to change/issues:

1. The `Foreground` is still in black although i have changed it.
2. My `boder` around the `Header`: i want to remove it in order to achieve this kind of style (the `header` is over the `border`):

[image]

3. All header is with upper case.

Edit:

After add the `style` that user @mm8 suggested, this is the results:

Why i can see duplicate border ?

[image]

Comment: If you don't want the looks of a groupbox, don't use it. Create your "GroupBox" using the Border and Grid controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your own set of controls to have full control, similar to this:

```
<Grid Width="100" Height="200" Background="DodgerBlue">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro">
        <TextBlock Foreground="Gainsboro">Header</TextBlock>
    </Border>

    <Border Grid.Row="1" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gainsboro">
        <!--Content-->
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Ok thats great but how can i put this TextBlock over my upper border (see the second picture i provided)

Comment: A good start could be using a negative margin: Margin="0,-10,0,0"

Comment: Well i did but still i want a bit space between my label and the border, i try to put the text with space, for example instead of "Header" i try "  Header  " but still the border is stuck to my TextBlock

Comment: Add a margin to the border <Border Margin="5">

Answer (score 3):

You could override the template for the `GroupBox`:

```
<GroupBox Header="My header" Style="{x:Null}">
    <GroupBox.Template>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupBox}">
            <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="6"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Column="0" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" CornerRadius="4" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3">
                    <Border.OpacityMask>
                        <MultiBinding ConverterParameter="7">
                            <MultiBinding.Converter>
                                <BorderGapMaskConverter />
                            </MultiBinding.Converter>
                            <Binding ElementName="Header" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                            <Binding Path="ActualWidth" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                            <Binding Path="ActualHeight" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Border.OpacityMask>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="3">
                        <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" CornerRadius="2"/>
                    </Border>
                </Border>
                <Border x:Name="Header" Grid.Column="1" Padding="3,1,3,0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Background="LightGreen" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="2" BorderThickness="1">
                    <ContentPresenter ContentSource="Header" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                </Border>
                <ContentPresenter Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </GroupBox.Template>
    <TextBlock>content...</TextBlock>
</GroupBox>
```

[image]

Comment: Set the Style property to {x:Null} to remove the MahApps style. I edited my answer.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, didn't this work out for you or why did you go with the alternative solution of creating seperate elements with different margins?